# while loop multiple statements

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I have some issues with looping. I am trying to loop multiple statements. Code is below.

```
int MenuSelect () {
    cout << endl;
    cout << YELLOW  << "Enter 1 for info" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 to Start" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 to view settings" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 4 to quit" << endl;

     int selected = 0;
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    if (stringstream(input) >> selected) {
        return selected;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;

};    

int Menu(int) {

    int selected {};
    while ((selected = MenuSelect()) == 1) {

        printmessage();


    }
    if (selected == 3) {

        cout << "Current Settings" << endl;

        somefunction();
    }

    else if (selected == 2) {

        cout << "Starting Game..... " << endl;
    }

    else if (selected == 4) {

        cout << "Exiting....." << endl;
        exit (3);
    }

    else {

        cout << "Invalid Entry" << endl;
        exit (3);
    }

    cout << "Below is the Deck of cards and you will get to choose 5 cards to play with. Choose wisely." << endl;

    return 0;

};
```

So as you can see the user can see the menu, then if and else statements do the work. At the moment I have managed to loop the first menu select so if the user enters 1 it will print the message and then loop back to the menu. What I want is to also loop the 3 - current settings and if the user enters a invalid number. I've tried to accomplish it but I can't seem to do it.

Comment: Move those `if`/`else if` blocks into the loop body, and then either change your loop condition to `while ((selected = MenuSelect()) > 0)` (works in this case since your `4` case just calls `exit`), or pull the `selected = MenuSelect()` out of the loop and run it again at the end of the loop body.

Comment: @0x5453 thank you that fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to repeatedly read user input and react accordingly? You can put all the `if`s into the `while`:

```
int Menu(int) {

    int selected {};
    bool loop = true;

    while (loop) {
        selected = MenuSelect();

        if(selected == 1) {
            printmessage();
        }
        else if (selected == 3) {
            cout << "Current Settings" << endl;

            somefunction();
        }
        else if (selected == 2) {
            cout << "Starting Game..... " << endl;
        }
        else if (selected == 4) {
            cout << "Exiting....." << endl;
            loop = false;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid Entry" << endl;
            loop = false;
        }
    }

    cout << "Below is the Deck of cards and you will get to choose 5 cards to play with. Choose wisely." << endl;

    return 0;

};
```

Using a variable `loop` to exit the `while` is just personal preference, you could as well have an endless loop

```
while(true)
```

and use `break;` to exit the loop or `exit()` to exit the whole program, as you do now.